# How do we add the Mesh: Snap_Utilities_Line tool to Object Mode?

Tags: mesh, add-on, tools, lines

How do we add the `Mesh: Snap_Utilities_Line` tool to *Object Mode*?

We can create full 3D shapes with it. It's an object creation tool as well

The `Mesh: Snap_Utilities_Line` tool is only in *Edit Mode* but it's a line tool we can use to trace architectural plans and also create full 3D objects using it. It is both an editing tool and object tool. How do we add it to *Object Mode*?

Comment: It seems to be only designed to be used in Edit mode according to the Blender [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/addons/mesh/snap_utilities_line.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#snap-utilities-line) entry so it's only for manipulating the mesh of existing objects not creating new ones which is what you seem to want.